# Magento install php memory error

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, memory-limit

I'm trying to install magento (1.8.0.0) inside a VM (Debian7 x64) for testing purposes.

When I try to open localhost/magento i get a php mermory error.

Magento reccomends a php memory limit of 512MB. I've increased this value even to 4096MB but the error still remains:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php on line 199

a phpinfo()-file shows me memory_limit=4096.

Moreover I've set

> php_value memory_limit 4096M

inside the .htaccess

Can anyone helm me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: 4096M is not enough.... (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) you need some more set the limit to 0

Comment: The strange thing is, "130968 bytes" keeps exactly always the same with every value I set as memory_limit.
I've tried to set memory_limit to -1 (php documentation) but the script aborted after 10min execution time.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/allowed_memory_size_exhausted